# Ionic CORS issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cors, ionic3

I'm facing CORS issue as expected for

- `1. ionic serve` and
- `2. ionic cordova run android`
- `3. ionic cordova build android --debug`

I resolved the issue for `1. ionic serve` using

- a local proxy in `ionic.config.json`

[as per this blog https://blog.ionicframework.com/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/](https://blog.ionicframework.com/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/)

```
"proxies": [
{
  "path": "/proxy",
  "proxyUrl": "https://xx.xx.xx/"
}
]
```

- set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in my POST calls like:

>

```
reqOpts = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH',
          'Accept':'application/json',
        })
      };
```

But using `2. ionic cordova run android` and `3. ionic cordova build android --debug` I still have the below error:

```
01-02 15:49:48.815 3682-3889/com.xx.xx D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost:8080/proxy/xx/login
01-02 15:49:48.859 3682-3682/com.xx.xx D/SystemWebChromeClient: http://localhost:8080/build/main.js: Line 834 : [object Object]
01-02 15:49:48.859 3682-3682/com.xx.xx I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(834)] "[object Object]", source: http://localhost:8080/build/main.js (834)
01-02 15:49:48.863 3682-3682/com.xx.xx D/SystemWebChromeClient: http://localhost:8080/build/vendor.js: Line 1823 : ERROR
01-02 15:49:48.864 3682-3682/com.xx.xx I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1823)] "ERROR", source: http://localhost:8080/build/vendor.js (1823)
```

The blog also mentions that when creating an APK cors won't be an issue. But if I remove the proxy and make an APK using `3. ionic cordova build android --debug`

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xx.xx.xx/xx/login' 
from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. main.js:835
```

Cors issue appears. Why does it occur for APKs for me? Shouldn't on device use the resources from file:// and not the localhost:// and thus avoid CORS issue?

And how do I

> a. fix the cors error

or

> b. make the proxy work for APK builds.

Oddly the server reply has Access-Control-Allow-Origin

```
Server →nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date →Thu, 03 Jan 2019 14:25:23 GMT
Content-Type →application/json
Content-Length →1010
Connection →keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →POST
```

ionic version: 4.5.0

OS: Mac OSX Mojave

platform: Android

Comment: You need to have access to your Login Server. There you need to set up CORS and you need to set there the Allowed Origins

Comment: The web service is from a 3rd party. Can this be handled from our side ?

Comment: There is an website called "AllowCorsEverywhere" this could help you. The next reason for this cors error is that you do your request via http on localhost. And maybe the security settings on the login server dont accept http requests. only https requests

Comment: btw did you set a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header at your request?

Comment: You can use this chrome plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc. Or

Comment: @phuwin the issue happens when the apk is running in device.

Comment: @Jonathan yes I added the headers. Mentioned it in question now.

Comment: When you use " * " as your Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header, this is called wildcard. You should set your `http://localhost:8080` as your Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header

Comment: tried both, adding the CORS headers makes the server send 405. It mean it doesn't allow them headers correct?

Comment: https://httpstatuses.com/405

Comment: what is version of ionic and which os(android or ios)?

Comment: ionic version: 4.5.0

OS: Mac OSX Mojave

platform: Android

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` are **response** headers, not request headers. They do no belong on your request options at all! Since you are using a proxy, they shouldn't even be needed on the response. You must have misconfigured the proxy.

Comment: @ir2pid: did you solve this? I have a similar problem, it only happens with my apk during a json fetch! I have wasted 2 days already trying to figure this one out...

Comment: 1.Debug to find the missing headers which are needed; with "ionic cordova run android" command and using chrome dev tool console. 2. work with your backend team to make sure they add all the respective missing headers  [Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, etc] to their responses and backend responds to OPTIONS method calls apart from GET, POST etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will always have CORS issues on WKWebview if you can't change the Server Settings, you can't do this by client. Suggestion, change to ionic native http

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/http/